# Fastest way to loop over 2 mixed arrays and return the matching value on intersection

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm trying to create a JavaScript method which loops over 2 arrays and returns an array of the matched value.

My a1 parameter in the 'getMatchedArray' method is an array of strings and objects, while arr2 is always array of objects.
However, a2 parameter in the 'getMatchedArray' method is an array that can contain an object with value property or without value property as seen in the sample arrays used.

I'm very close to it but somehow not able to figure out, what is the mistake I'm making?
Is there a faster way using intersection to achieve this?

```js
const arr1 = ["red", {
  "code": "red",
  "label": "test"
}, {
  "code": "blue",
  "label": "test1"
}, "white", "blue", {
  "code": "red",
  "label": "test2"
}];
const arr2 = [{
  "code": "red",
  "value": "test2"
}];
const arr3 = [{
  "code": "blue"
}];
const arr4 = [{
  "code": "red",
  "value": "test3"
}]

function getMatchedArray(a1, a2) {
  return a1.reduce((memo, opt) => {
    const isOptionFound = a2.some(obj => {
      if (obj.value) {
        return obj.value === opt.label;
      } else {
        return !opt.code && opt === obj.code;
      }
    });
    if (isOptionFound) {
      memo.push(opt);
    }
    return memo;
  }, []);
}
const result1 = getMatchedArray(arr1, arr2);
const result2 = getMatchedArray(arr1, arr3);
const result3 = getMatchedArray(arr1, arr4);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

Expected output:

result1:

```
[{
  "code": "red",
  "label": "test2"
}]
```

result2: `["blue"]`

result3: `["red"]`

result1, result 2 are fine, but my result3 is incorrect.
Any help on this?

Comment: I added an answer with the live demo. Can you please have a look. I hope it will work as per the requirement and expectation.

Comment: Why should the third result contain red? Why not empty result, given that there is no match that would be red with a label of test3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this requirement by separating the string and object elements from an array and then applied filter on those arrays based on the passed 2nd parameter in the function by `stringify` the passed parameters in the function.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr1 = ["red", {
  "code": "red",
  "label": "test"
}, {
  "code": "blue",
  "label": "test1"
}, "white", "blue", {
  "code": "red",
  "label": "test2"
}];

const arr2 = [{
  "code": "red",
  "value": "test2"
}];

const arr3 = [{
  "code": "blue"
}];

const arr4 = [{
  "code": "red",
  "value": "test3"
}];

function getMatchedArray(a1, a2) {
  let strA2 = JSON.stringify(a2);
  
  const strArrayFromA1 = a1.filter(item => typeof item === 'string');
  const objArrayFromA1 = a1.filter(item => typeof item === 'object');

  const matchedObject = objArrayFromA1.filter(elem => {
    strA2 = strA2.replaceAll('value', 'label');
    return strA2.includes(JSON.stringify(elem));
  });
  
  const matchedString = strArrayFromA1.filter(elem => strA2.includes(elem));

  return matchedObject.length ? matchedObject : matchedString.length ? matchedString : 'No match found.';
}

const result1 = getMatchedArray(arr1, arr2);
const result2 = getMatchedArray(arr1, arr3);
const result3 = getMatchedArray(arr1, arr4);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this  
  function findMatchingValues(arr1, arr2) {
      const hashTable = {};
      const matchingValues = [];
      
      // Populate hash table with values from arr1
      for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        const val = arr1[i];
        hashTable[val] = true;
      }
      
      // Check arr2 for matching values
      for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        const val = arr2[i];
        if (hashTable[val]) {
          matchingValues.push(val);
        }
      }
      
      return matchingValues;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the expected output has to be from arr1 as shown above in the question.